# SQL query to exclude numbers, brackets or special characters at the end of a name

Tags: sql, numbers, special-characters, suffix, filter-run-excluding

I'm trying to exclude all names with numbers in it, but still include certain special characters like:
()-'

So far, i've got this query:

SELECT FirstName FROM Client WHERE FirstName NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%';

This excludes most names with numbers in it, however, a few like the following are still coming through (not being excluded):

[image]

How do i exclude these from above, but still keep rows that look like the ones below:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't have a `^` in your character class

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, using SQL Server *sorry for not specifying*

Comment: @Mo_Dlg . . . Your query doesn't come close to returning that result set:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4034f49c87c35085918aa3fbdd58ba60.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm trying to exclude all names with numbers in it.

Assuming you are using SQL Server, your logic has too many negations.  You want:

```
WHERE FirstName NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%';
```

This translates to `FirstName` not having any number in it.

If you want names that are only alphabetical and spaces, then use:

```
WHERE FirstName NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z ]%';
```

Your version simply states that the string has no character which is not like a digit -- that is, it consists only of digits.

Comment: You're right @Gordon Linoff & THANK YOU! I've updated the question to not just be only alphabets & spaces, but to ensure certain characters are included     '-()

Comment: @Mo_Dlg . . . The first query does what you are asking for.

Comment: Apologies, i've focussed on the 2nd query posted only, not realising. The first one works perfect - thank you!